# Is asking for a website performing specs comparison on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Example](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2695/12202) from [Mawg says reinstate Monica](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6200/mawg-says-reinstate-monica):

> I am shopping for a new Android and would like a web site where I can do side by side comparisons, especially if I can start by entering my preferred spec. I can't seem to find one my Googling.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am a pretty new user and not a mod, please take my answer with a grain of salt.

I think it's not as a question, but I think it's fair to give it as an answer if it's useful to give recommendations. Since that site isn't hardware, but software, I think it should go on software recs SE.